# Remove adjacent identical elements in a Ruby Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Ruby 1.8.6

I have an array containing numerical values. I want to reduce it such that sequences of the same value are reduced to a single instance of that value.

So I want

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

to reduce to

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

As you can see, `Array#uniq` won't work in this case.

I have the following, which works:

```
(a.size - 1).downto(1) { |i| a[i] = nil if a[i - 1] == a[i] }
```

Can anyone come up with something less ugly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the simplest, leanest solution, you could use the method [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
a.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)
```

The `itself` method is Ruby 2.2+. Use `{|n| n}` if you are stuck in an older Ruby, or my [`backports`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gems.
It was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2. If you're unlucky enough to be using older rubies, you could use my backports gem and `require 'backports/1.9.2/enumerable/chunk'`.

Comment: You don't need x.first, you can simply say .map(&:first)

Comment: @DarkMouse You did in 1.8.6 :-) actually. This was relevant 4 years ago, but not much today. I've updated my answer

Comment: As of Ruby 2.2, `a.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)` works and looks a little nicer.

Answer (score 5):

```
a.inject([]){|acc,i| acc.last == i ? acc : acc << i }
```

Comment: I got to this one as well, once I remembered `#inject`. It's certainly cleaner than the attempt I posted and it's a lot more "Rubyish". The `#chunk` thing is hard to beat, though...

Answer (score 1):

I can think only of this

```
a.each_with_index{|item,i| a[i] = nil if a[i] == a[i+1] }.compact
```

but it is more or less the same.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are *very* concerned with the speed that block will calculate at, I would suggest you simply add this line to the end of your block to get the desired output:

```
a.compact!
```

That will just remove all the `nil` elements you introduced to the array earlier (the would-be duplicates), forming your desired output: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]`

If you want another algorithm, here is something *far uglier* than yours. :-)

```
require "pp"

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

i = 0

while i < a.size do
  e = a[i]
  j = i

  begin
    j += 1
  end while e == a[j]

  for k in i+1..j-1 do
    a[k] = nil
  end

  i = j
end

pp a
a.compact!
pp a
```

Gives you the output:

```
[1, nil, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, nil, nil, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, nil]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

In my opinion, your code is fine. Just add the `a.compact!` call and you are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

another solution:

```
acc = [a[0]]
a.each_cons(2) {|x,y| acc << y if x != y}
```

or

```
a.each_cons(2).inject([a[0]]) {|acc, (x,y)| x == y ? acc : acc << y}
```

Comment: I seem to forget about `require 'enumerator'`, which is often a mistake. I bet I could find a dozen places in my code where I should have used `#each_cons`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are all single digits 0-9: `a.join.squeeze('0-9').each_char.to_a` should work.

Comment: In my case they aren't, but you've given me the name for the method if I monkey-patch: `Array#squeeze`