# Remove sequential duplicates from Ruby array

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have the following array and I would like to get rid of contiguous duplicates:

```
arr = [1,1,1,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,1,1,1]
```

I would like to get the following:

```
=> [1,4,3,5,1]
```

It would be great if there's something simpler and more efficient than my solutions (or variants thereof):

```
(arr + [nil]).each_cons(2).collect { |i| i[0] != i[1] ? i[0] : nil }.compact
```

or

```
(arr + [nil]).each_cons(2).each_with_object([]) { 
   |i, memo| memo << i[0] unless i[0] == i[1] 
 }
```

**EDIT:**
It looks like @ArupRakshit's solution below is very simple. I'm still looking for better efficiency than my solution.

**EDIT:**

I'll be benchmarking responses as they come:

```
require 'fruity'
arr = 10000.times.collect { [rand(5)] * (rand(4) + 2) }.flatten

compare do
  abdo { (arr + [nil]).each_cons(2).collect { 
    |i| i[0] != i[1] ? i[0] : nil }.compact 
  }
  abdo2 { 
          (arr + [nil]).each_cons(2).each_with_object([]) { 
           |i, memo| memo << i[0] unless i[0] == i[1] 
          }
  }
  arup { arr.chunk(&:to_i).map(&:first) }
  arupv2 { arr.join.squeeze.chars.map(&:to_i) }
  agis {
    i = 1
    a = [arr.first]

    while i < arr.size
      a << arr[i] if arr[i] != arr[i-1]
      i += 1
     end
    a
  }
  arupv3 { arr.each_with_object([]) { |el, a| a << el if a.last != el } }
end
```

Benchmark results:

```
agis is faster than arupv3 by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
arupv3 is faster than abdo2 by 1.9x ± 0.1
abdo2 is faster than abdo by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
abdo is faster than arup by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
arup is faster than arupv2 by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```

If we use:

```
arr = 10000.times.collect { rand(4) + 1 } # less likelihood of repetition
```

We get:

```
agis is faster than arupv3 by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
arupv3 is faster than abdo2 by 1.9x ± 0.1
abdo2 is similar to abdo
abdo is faster than arupv2 by 2.1x ± 0.1
arupv2 is similar to arup
```

Comment: "I'll be benchmarking responses as they come"... followed by acceptance of the first answer, ensuring responses *won't* come...

Comment: I'm sure people (especially Rubyists) don't stop posting after an answer has been accepted.

Comment: How is this `arr.join.squeeze.chars.map(&:to_i)` ? Does it response good ? :)

Comment: Some might, but it's a huge disincentive. Personally I have limited time and tend to scan for unanswered questions.

Comment: @ArupRakshit haha, ANOTHER beautiful solution! your other one is about 30% faster. (updating benchmarks) But hey.. you should def post as answer as I'm sure others would appreciate it!

Comment: @MarkThomas I totally understand your point but at the same time, over the past few days, I've seen a bunch of guys (such as: aruprakshit, careswoveland, steenslag, matt) answering questions from a while ago and improving them just for because they enjoy to!

Comment: @Abdo *arup is faster than arupv2*.. So let it be in a comment itself.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it depends on the repetitions of the contiguous subarrays in the array ... sometimes arup is faster, sometimes arupv2 is faster.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, just as long as you know you're limiting your potential audience.

Comment: @Abdo check my answer. It's the faster way :)

Comment: @MarkThomas - You're missing out on some good answering.  It's not uncommon to find that the accepted answer can be improved on considerably.  It's a good feeling when you can post a better answer; even better when the checkmark gets moved to your answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit your new answer is GREAT! It performs better than all the others except for agis' . Yours is much clearer syntax though :-)

Comment: Thinking to write down an email to **Matz**, by saying that, we are happy with *loop*, we would write our methods by own, stop increasing the API load.. Lollzz.. :)

Comment: Why would you prefer a slightly faster solution over a clearer one?  Is this code a demonstrated bottleneck in your application?

Comment: @WayneConrad I have accepted the clearer solution below as you can see =) Check my comments on Agis' response :-)

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, perhaps I'm wrong. Or this is a special case because it's a particularly interesting question. In any case, there's some good stuff here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove adjacent identical elements in a Ruby Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516312/remove-adjacent-identical-elements-in-a-ruby-array)

Comment: @MarkThomas looks like it except that we have a few faster solutions here :-)

Comment: @Abdo Agreed. But there are more valid answers there so it's a good reference.

Comment: @MarkThomas had I seen it before, I wouldn't have asked this question. It simply did not appear in my search results... In any case, I think duplicate questions are not necessarily bad. Maybe a new one ends up getting picked up by search engines better =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do as below using [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) :

```
arr = [1,1,1,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,1,1,1]
arr.chunk { |e| e }.map(&:first)
# => [1, 4, 3, 5, 1]
# if you have only **Fixnum**, something magic
arr.chunk(&:to_i).map(&:first)
# => [1, 4, 3, 5, 1]
```

**UPDATE**

as per [*@abdo's*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730055/remove-sequential-duplicates-from-ruby-array#comment32864411_21730055) comment, here is another choice :

```
arr.join.squeeze.chars.map(&:to_i)
# => [1, 4, 3, 5, 1]
```

**another choice**

```
arr.each_with_object([]) { |el, a| a << el if a.last != el }
```

Comment: It looks like mine are faster :s .. I'll post benchmarks above

Comment: @Abdo Done.. Don't remove( from the original comment box) the linked comment of your in my answer. :)

Comment: @Abdo check again! :)

Comment: The `join.squeeze` method will only work for single digit numbers.  The first solution is very nice: it is succinct, easy to understand, works with any comparable data type, and is almost certainly _fast enough_.

Comment: @WayneConrad I am also not happy with that one, its long method chain, should I remove it ? :)

Comment: @WayneConrad I like the different (educational) approach taken by `join.squeeze` in case we're using characters vs numbers and am glad aruprakshit provided alternatives :-)

Answer (score 4):

The less *elegant* yet most *efficient* solution:

```
require 'benchmark'

arr = [1,1,1,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,1,1,1]

GC.disable
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    1_000_000.times do
      i = 1
      a = [arr.first]

      while i < arr.size
        a << arr[i] if arr[i] != arr[i-1]
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
#      user     system      total        real
# 1.890000   0.010000   1.900000 (  1.901702)

GC.enable; GC.start; GC.disable

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    1_000_000.times do
      (arr + [nil]).each_cons(2).collect { |i| i[0] != i[1] ? i[0] : nil }.compact
    end
  end
end
#      user     system      total        real
# 6.050000   0.680000   6.730000 (  6.738690)
```

Comment: Yup, this is at least 2x faster than my fastest solution. (My benchmarks are different because I'm using a larger array).
Your solution, however, is buggy: can you try: `agis([0,1,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,1])` => returning  `[0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1]` expected:  `[0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 1]` . Let me know when fixed so I can post alongside my benchmarks =)

Comment: I doubt, how many Ruby coder would use, such a *loop* for this kind of solution.. :)

Comment: @Agis, you get a +1. ArupRakshit 's last solution is very close in efficiency to your solution. His solution, however, is much easier on the eyes. My question required BOTH simplicity and efficiency.